# Does Unity 3d cost money?

Tags: unity

So I installed an Unity engine and I want to develop games by that.
I heard that it costs 1500$ to program the code and post the game. Is that true? Did some1 developed a game with it and uploaded it to the Play Store?

Comment: quick browse on their website shows [this comparison](http://unity3d.com/unity/licenses) about what you need to pay for

Comment: yeah, sometimes could be helpful at least check company website for informations

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it about the spec/pricing data for a particular software product.

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not true. It does cost that much for full professional access, but you can program and sell a game with the base free feature-set:
[License comparison](http://unity3d.com/unity/licenses)